# Vue3 Composable return value as Component prop

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

In vue composition API, I have a composable that returns an object with some Ref variables and function references.

Example:

```ts
type UseVehicle = {
  speedInMph: Ref<number>;
}

const useVehicle = (speedInKmh: number): UseVehicle => {
  const speedInMph = computed(() => speedInKmh / 1.609);
  return { speedInMph };
}
```

And I have a component that expects a prop with the type of `UseVehicle`.
Example:

```ts
interface VehicleDetailsProps {
  vehicle: UseVehicle;
}

const props = defineProps<VehicleDetailsProps>();
```

In my component how can I use the `speedInMph` as a reactive variable?

I tried `computed(() => props.vehicle.speedInMph`, `toRef`, `toRefs` as well, but even tho my IDE says the type of the variable is `Ref<number>`, it is not a reactive variable in the `<script setup>` context, `watch` is not being triggered on changed for example.

---

Playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-s7wnmc?file=vehicle-details.vue

As you can see the `watch` only runs on mount (because of `immediate: true`) and never runs again.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-2e99jd?file=vehicle-details.vue) what you're looking for?  Basically, in your watch, remove `() =>` because `speedInMph` is a ref, so you can just watch that.  Although, props are typically unwrapped when they're passed in, but because `vehicle` is an object, this doesn't happen to its properties.  Maybe this is OK for your project, but I'd be careful with doing things like that.